# What is the different between string and string? in C# when use it to get input

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

[[string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OWM4.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bniDM.png)

what is different??
why does it give an error?

Comment: Don't paste images of code in your question - go back and paste the code as text, using the `{}` button to format it as `code`. Look up _Nullable Reference Types_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references. `string?` declares a variable as a _nullable string_

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main difference: in case of **'String'** type you are bound to have an input string , nulls are not expected, But if you use **'String?'** then your function can work even if the string value is null.
Example: **public string EntryKey { get; set; } --> 'String'** it cannot be null.
While in case of 'string?' it can be null you have to set it like: `string abc = default.`

```
string notNull = "Hello";

string? nullable = default;

notNull = nullable!; // null forgiveness
```

Comment: It's not quite that simple. It's more about letting the compiler know about the programmer's intent. In your example `EntryKey` can be set to null. The compiler will warn if you say `EntryKey = null;`, but it also won't check if you don't do null checks before using `EntryKey`; it's assumed to be non-null. Read the article I posted above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references